# Would like to get http response results like Fiddler

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get the same type of results that Fiddler gets when I launch a webpage from my app.
Below is the code I'm using and the results I'm getting.  I've used google.com only as an example.

What do I need to modify in my code to get the results I want or do I need an entirely different approach?

Thanks for your help.

My code:

```
 // create the HttpWebRequest object
        HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");

        // get the response object which has the header info, using the GetResponse method
        var objResults = objRequest.GetResponse(); 

        // get the header count
        int intCount = objResults.Headers.Count;

        // loop through the results object
        for (int i = 0; i < intCount; i++)
        {
            string strKey = objResults.Headers.GetKey(i);
            string strValue = objResults.Headers.Get(i);


            lblResults.Text += strKey + "<br />" + strValue + "</br /><br />";
        }
```

My results:

Cache-Control
private, max-age=0

Content-Type
text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

Date
Tue, 05 Jun 2012 17:40:38 GMT

Expires
-1

Set-Cookie
PREF=ID=526197b0260fd361:FF=0:TM=1338918038:LM=1338918038:S=gefqgwkuzuPJlO3G; expires=Thu, 05-Jun-2014 17:40:38 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com,NID=60=CJbpzMe6uTKf58ty7rysqUFTW6GnsQHZ-Uat_cFf1AuayffFtJoFQSIwT5oSQKqQp5PSIYoYtBf_8oSGh_Xsk1YtE7Z834Qwn0A4Sw3ruVCA9v3f_UDYH4b4fAloFJbW; expires=Wed, 05-Dec-2012 17:40:38 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly

P3P
CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."

Server
gws

X-XSS-Protection
1; mode=block

X-Frame-Options
SAMEORIGIN

Transfer-Encoding
chunked

=========================
Fiddler results:

## Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom

1   304 HTTP    www.rolandgarros.com    /images/misc/weather/P8.gif 0   max-age=700  Expires: Tue, 05 Jun 2012 17:53:40 GMT image/gif   firefox:5456
2   200 HTTP    www.google.com  /   23,697  private, max-age=0  Expires: -1 text/html; charset=UTF-8    chrome:2324
3   304 HTTP    www.rolandgarros.com    /images/misc/weather/P9.gif 0   max-age=700  Expires: Tue, 05 Jun 2012 17:53:57 GMT image/gif   firefox:5456
4   200 HTTP    Tunnel to   translate.googleapis.com:443    0           chrome:2324
5   200 HTTP    www.google.com

Answer (score 3):

The difference is Fiddler is actually recording an entire session, not just a single HTTP request.

If a user loads Google.com, the response is typically an HTML document which contains images, script files, CSS files, etc.  Your browser will then initiate a new HTTP request for each one of those resources.  With Fiddler running, it tracks each of those HTTP requests and spits out the result code and other information about the session.

With your C# code above, you're only initiating a single HTTP request, thus you only have information about a single result.

You'd probably be better off writing a browser plugin.  Otherwise, you'd have to parse the HTML response and load other resources from that document as well.

If you *do* need to do this with C# code, you could probably parse the document with the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and then look for other resources within the HTML to simulate a browser.  There's also embedded browsers, such as [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/), that might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are not asking for the same information that Fiddler is displaying.  Fiddler shows the HTTP Status code, the host and URI and (it appears, from your example) the Content Length, Content Type and Cache status.

For many of these you will have to peek in to the response headers.